# Have the Tree Lounge Advantage patents expired?

Tags: ownership, legal-status, assignment, us5954158

I was wondering if the Tree Lounge Advantage patents (e.g., [US 5,954,158](http://www.google.com/patents/US5954158)) are available to be purchased? I know the company has since closed. Have they expired or are they still valid? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

On the Google Patents page for this patent, look under Legal Events and you will see:

```
Nov 13, 2007    FP  Expired due to failure to pay maintenance fee
Effective date: 20070921
```

The patent is expired since September 9, 2007.

If you are interested in the detailed history of the patent, refer to the [USPTO Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) database.